# Убрать CSS в webbrowser

Tags: css, delphi, webbrowser

Сразу к делу. Пытаюсь программно решить reCaptcha на сайте https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo
После решения картинок нужно получить ответ(ключ) Его не видно в HTML коде страницы, но его видно если отключить css страницу - внизу появится окно в котором будет код.
 Собственно возникли сложности, как такое сделать в webbrowser. Или в Chromium, может вообще есть способ получить этот ответ не отключая css страницы.
Или есть ли вариант создать свой css для всех страниц и настроить работу IE таким образом. Буду очень благодарен.
http://prnt.sc/dup5sh

Comment: может быть не легче не отключать css, а сделать блок который закрывает ключ прозрачным? или может это окно сдвинуто за пределы видимой области браузера. тогда нужно дать ему margin или position или translate.

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov можно подробнее?

Answer (score 0):

Ну в общем есть несколько способов с помощью css спрятать какой-нибудь элемент от пользователя. Не претендуя на перечисление всех вариантов...

1. Прозрачность. По наведению мыши я делаю закрывающий блок прозрачным.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.child {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  transition: 1s;
}
.child:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  1597814
  <div class="child">
    наведи мышь
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Позиционирование. Может быть сделано что помощью свойств margin, position или transform: translate, суть одна и та же - то что нужно скрыть сдвигает за границы видимой области браузера.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  transition: .2s;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
.parent:hover {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  1597814
  <div class="child">
    наведи мышь
  </div>
</div>
```

Так вот. Вам нужно найти элемент которому применены такие средства сокрытия его от глаз пользователя и принудительно дать этому блоку такие css-свойства, чтобы он был виден.

Comment: Выглядит впечатляюще! Я что то понял. А вы не могли бы немного рассказать как это реализовать. Я понял что моих знаний и опыта еще не достаточно. Хочу научится.

Comment: Когда ваша капча будет решена откройте инспектор браузера (Ctrl+Shift+I) и посмотрите какой класс или идентификатор у блока который закрывает ключ. Этому блоку нужно доступным вам образом поменять css-свойства. Как это сделать на дельфи я не знаю.

Comment: возможно ли это сделать джаваскриптом? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2530497/4908529

Comment: можно. например в случае с прозрачностью `document.getElementById('{идентификатор элемента закрывающего ключ}').style.opacity = '0';`